# How to host a video conference with VLVC?

Tags: video, vlc

I just found out that you can use VLC and [VLVC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vlvc/) to hold video conferences between 2-10 people, and that sounds amazing, hopefully removing the heavy lean on Skype.

Can anyone tell me how to set up VLVC for video conferencing? I can't seem to figure it out right now. I am sure it is easy, but I just seem to be stuck at the moment.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: I suppose I can close this, I am no longer interested, but it would be a benefit for others. With Google Hangouts I do not really have a need for this. Perhaps I will close this question this weekend. thanks for the bump on this question I had forgot about it.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I would like to suggest trying [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) messenger for voice/video chat

Comment: Adding Jitsi as an alternative is a good choice @Sepero. Maybe you wish to add a question with self-answer to have that excellent suggestion around so that people will come to the site for information. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This project is still in Beta. You got to http://sourceforge.net/projects/vlvc/ and install the plugin in vlc. When you run the plugin you can attach to the IP hosting the conference, or host one yourself. You will need to put yourself in the DMZ of your router so that you can host a conference or forward the chosen ports.

Comment: That means this doesn't work on most mobile broadband connections, coz they don't have routers. :(

Comment: @Naveen Not really. Since there is no router, there is nothing to confuse forwarding and routing, assuming you get a separate IP address via mobile broadband.

Comment: yeah this is definitely for someone who has a public ip on their home router which is rare.